# creating login for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to create a new user and later set permissions to different tables in two different databases. This is my script to create the user

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'something' , CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

CREATE ROLE MyRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyRole', N'MyUser'
GO
```

Now I have two database MyDb1 and MyDb2. I need to grant select access for this user to MyDb1.Table1 and MyDb2.Table2. Do I need to create this users for MyDb1 and MyDb2 first? If so how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CREATE LOGIN` is in context of the whole SQL Server, while `CREATE USER` and `CREATE ROLE` are in the context of each database. You will need to create the user and the role in both MyDb1 and MyDb2 and grant permissions in each. Try this

```
USE MASTER
GO

CREATE LOGIN [MyUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'something' , CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

USE MyDb1
GO

CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

CREATE ROLE MyRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyRole', N'MyUser'
GO

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table1 TO MyRole
GO

USE MyDb2
GO

CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

CREATE ROLE MyRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyRole', N'MyUser'
GO

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table2 TO MyRole
GO
```